# How to increate mp3 speed (enable and increase the rate) in Android

Tags: android, mp3, android-audiomanager

How to increase or decrease the speed of a mp3 using the Audio player in Android?

iOS has the below code to increase or decrease the speed.
`_noticeAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Rooster-mono" ofType:@"wav"]]
                                                      error:nil];;
if ([_noticeAudio respondsToSelector:@selector(setEnableRate:)])
    _noticeAudio.enableRate = YES;
if ([_noticeAudio respondsToSelector:@selector(setRate:)])
    _noticeAudio.rate = 2.0;`

How can i achieve the same in Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution from a query ([How to slow down and stretch audio in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6886390/how-to-slow-down-and-stretch-audio-in-android))

Used the

> android.media.SoundPool

to achieve the speed rate for mp3 audio.